# getDefinitionByName not finding a variable that exists

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using *flash.utils.getDefinitionByName* in an attempt to grab an art asset. I use this function quite a bit and haven't had trouble until now. Check it:

```
assetName = Assets.MegaBerry; // works
assetName = getDefinitionByName("Assets.MegaBerry") as Class; // doesn't work
```

What the heck?? Error response for the second line is "*Variable not found.*"

If it matters: Assets is a file in my root source directory (it has no package; Assets is the fully qualified name) and I've tried putting:

```
import Assets;
```

at the top with no luck.

For reference, in Assets.as I have:

```
    [Embed(source = "../art/Inventory/MegaBerry.png")]
    public static var MegaBerry:Class;
```

Comment: Have you tried "Assets::MegaBerry"? If that doesn't work, call getQualifiedClassName(Assets.MegaBerry) and check what the output of that is.  getQualifiedClassName and getDefinitionByName are a pair so output of one is the input of the other generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that embedding the resource into the `Assets` class will create a static variable of type `Class` that belongs to that class - which is what you are referencing when you use `Assets.MegaBerry`: A variable(!) of type Class.

<strike>It does not, however, register the MegaBerry class to a fully qualified class *name*. To do this, you have to use - who would have guessed it - `registerClassAlias` at some point in your application:</strike>

```
registerClassAlias("Assets.MegaBerry", Assets.MegaBerry);
```

After that, it will be available everywhere else when calling `getDefinitionByName`.

** **EDIT** **

Well that's some unexpected behavior...  It turns out, the class that was embedded *is in fact automatically registered*, but under `{className}_{variableName}`, instead of the notation you would expect.  So using:

```
getDefinitionByName("Assets_MegaBerry") as Class;
```

should to the trick.

`registerClassAlias` also works, but then you need to call `getClassByAlias`instead of `getDefinitionByName`. Sorry for the mix-up.

** **END EDIT** **

You can also use the Embed tag to inject the resource into a separate class file, which you can then reference as expected by using `getDefinitionByName`, or simply using an import:

```
package assets {

    [Embed(source="../art/Inventory/MegaBerry.png"]
    public class MegaBerry extends BitmapData {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, what you say makes sense but I can't get it to work. Added the registerClassAlias right before the erroring assetName call, and it's still saying it can't find it. :/

Comment: While the separate-file-for-the-asset does the trick, it's a bit unwieldly... I'm going to have hundreds of images and keeping them all in one file, one line of code each, is definitely preferable.

Comment: I have found a solution and corrected my answer.  See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling

```
assetName = getDefinitionByName("Assets.MegaBerry") as Class;
```

, instead just use:

```
assetName = Assets["MegaBerry"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 [Embed(source = "../art/Inventory/MegaBerry.png" , symbol="MegaBerry")]
 public static var MegaBerry:Class;
```

Comment: "symbol" is not supported by the image transcoder, so says my compiler. :/

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript, objects actually have a name property that is different from the actual variable name as it shows in code.

For example, if you create a variable as follows,

```
var myBerry = new MegaBerry();
```

Then `getDefinitionByName("myBerry")` will return null.

Only when you set the *name* of the variable by writing `myBerry.name = "myBerry"`, will `getDefinitionByName("myBerry")` return what you want it to. The *name* of the object doesn't necessarily have to be equal to the variable name in code.

In your specific case, I don't think you need to use any of that anyways. Have you tried `assetName = new MegaBerry()` ?

Comment: I guess the question was a teensy bit misleading thanks to my simplification of the problem, but the string "MegaBerry" is procedurally generated (it COULD be "MegaPie001" or "MegaBerry17").

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening here. Why are you creating several MegaBerry *classes* when you should be creating *instances* of those classes?

Comment: Setting that `name`property on a Class does not really do anything for me, except store a string...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out what the *fully qualified name* of you class really is, you may do the following:

```
trace(getQualifiedClassName(Assets.MegaBerry));
```

You may do that from inside Assets.as, for instance.

You can feed that string back to `getDefinitionByName()` and get a reference to the class.

```
trace(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(SomeClass)));
// output [class SomeClass]
```

And remember, `getDefinitionByName()` only gets you references for classes that are in the same scope as the getDefinitionByName call itself. So, if you are loading external SWFs, getting class references will depend on the application domain you are using and the place, where this code executes.